# estimating distance between two raspberry in same wifi network using RSSI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wifi, distance, rssi

I am currently working on a small project and I need your help regarding the estimation of the distance between two raspberries in the same wifi network I tried to research on the RSSI technique by exploiting the strength of the signal. is this the only technique i can use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.